# Codeigniter, "call to a member function get() on a non-object" error only from the model

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call to a member function get() on a non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024468/call-to-a-member-function-get-on-a-non-object)

I autoload the database library.

Here is my Controller

```
class Orders extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('orders_model');

}

public function index()
{
    echo $this->orders_model->test();
    $data['orders'] = $this->orders_model->get_orders();
```

and here is my Model

```
class Orders_model extends CI_Model {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();


}

public function get_orders($slug = FALSE)
{

if ($slug === FALSE)
    {

        $query = $this->db->get('table1');
        return $query->result_array();
    }


    $query = $this->db->get_where('table1', array('numtest' => $slug));
    return $query->row_array();

}
public function test()
{
    $text = "return test";
    return $text;
}
```

For troubleshooting purposes I moved the code from the model to the controller executed the code successfully. Somehow though, it does not function when I try and do the get() call from my Model. Also, calling the test() function from within the Model works successfully.

Comment: You got error on this line ? $query = $this->db->get('table1'); Try to check the last query using echo $this->db->last_query(); after running the get() function. Check whether  the query is right or not. does 'table1' table exist in your database?

Comment: yes. table1 exists. I ran the get() function and loaded the page successfully when the get() function lived within the controller and I didn't call the Model. However, when get() lives within the Model it gives me that error.

Comment: I don't think you have a database connection running $this->db is not an object. Make sure this is set $db['YOUR_CONNECTION_NAME']['autoinit'] = TRUE; in your application/config/database.php file.

Comment: I suspect that there is no database connection, but why is there a connection in the Controller and not in the Model if I autoload the database library? I already have that line in my database.php file.

Comment: do you have a default database selected otherwise you need to specify it as far as I know.

Comment: $active_group = 'YOUR_CONNECTIO_NAME';

Comment: yes, i only have one database for the application and it is my default.

Comment: Do you have $active_record=TRUE;

Comment: yes, I have it in my database.php file as well.

Comment: I tried to run $this->load->database(); in the construct function, and the error is now " Call to a member function database() on a non-object"

Comment: This would happen when the object is not constructed and actually there is no `db` library to use in that context.

Comment: @MahanGM, if I'm autoloading the library for the entire application why would it not be available in that specific context?

Answer (score 0):

Try to force the connection with the database in the loading of your model.
You can use:

```
$this->load->model('orders_model', '', TRUE);
```